# VS 2017 Enterprise CodeLense Not Working

Tags: model-view-controller, visual-studio-2017, enterprise

so I just got VS Enterprise 2017 but the thing is codelense is disabled (checkbox not checked) and when I check it and exit options it automatically gets unchecked.

any help need it please.

Comment: what are you using for source control?

Comment: directly TFS, not git

Comment: others on same project has it working perfectly

Comment: Try signing into visual studio again.   If that does not help do a repair on visual studio 2017

Comment: thanks did the repair...worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and trying alot of things, I found out that the problem is because of Resharper, if I install it the CodeLens becomes disabled and can not be enabled. don't know why though.